# [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I've tried to install promox on a dl380 g6, with a usb. The installer loads, and when I choose the option to install promox, this error shows:

> [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources

Other info:

HP BIOS P62 10/01/2009
Promox VE 5.1

Comment: Does the installer continue?

Comment: @ewwhite This id what it does after that error https://m.imgur.com/a/5qoAo